# after compare two different tables , it will find matches then print in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server

For example , i have a two different tables like :

**Table A-----**

```
 - id -   - name -  - birthday -
   1        Adam        1970
   2        Sarah       1980
```

**Table B-----**

```
 - id -   - name -  - birthday -
   1        Frank       1956
   2        Adam        1990
   3        Sarah       1980
```

I want this result in datagrid :

```
 - id -   - name -  - birthday -
   1        Sarah       1980
```

Comment: Show your code, what did you tried?

Comment: Use an inner join.

Comment: i made 2 different user table. i need to compare them with each other and find sames in compare then i need to print them into datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the tables

```
select A.id as id,
       A.name as name,
       A.birthday as birthday
  from TableA A inner join 
       TableB B on (A.name = B.name) and (A.birthday = B.birthday)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableA
intersect
select * from tableB
```

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/

Comment: that is true but my tables has different columns so i make the compare with 1 column

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a INTERSECT of the tables.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

```
SELECT col1, col2,...,colN
FROM TableA
INTERSECT
SELECT col1, col2,...,colN
FROM TableB;
```